# How to create a custom bullet-shaped gauge using Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly-python

How to create a custom bullet-shaped gauge using Plotly?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(
    go.Indicator(
        mode = "number+gauge+delta",
        gauge = {'shape': "bullet",
            'axis': {'range': [0, max]},
            'threshold': {
            'line': {'color': "black", 'width': 3},
            'thickness': 0.75, 'value': actual_value},
            'steps': [
                {'range': [0, 100], 'color': "#1E9600"},
                {'range': [100, 200], 'color': "#FFF200"},
                {'range': [200,300], 'color': "#FF0000"}],
            'bar': {'color': "black"}
            },
        value = 270,
        delta = {'reference': 300,'font': {"size": 12}},
        number = {'prefix': " ",'font': {"size": 12}},
        domain = {'x': [0.20, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
        title = {'text': "Price Range:",'font': {"size": 12}}
        )
    )
fig.update_layout(height = 200, font =  {"size": 12})
fig.show()
```

This Python code uses the Plotly library to create an indicator with a bullet-shaped gauge.

The indicator displays the current value of a metric, along with a gauge and a delta value. The gauge has a black bar and three colored regions that represent ranges of values. The delta value represents the difference between the current value and a reference value.

Comment: Your question has a code and a graphic, but it does not say what the question is about. Please write what you would like to do.